# How to scale a texture on a Texture Atlas while maintaining its offset?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

How can I scale a specific texture on a texture atlas in GLSL while ignoring the other textures? For example, let's say I have a texture Atlas that has 16 textures.

[image]

I found the texture I need using this formula:

```c
float scale = 1.0/0.25;
vec2 idx = vec2(1.0,2.0);
vec2 newUvForTexture = (vUv+idx)*scale;
vec4 tex = texture2D(texArray[0],newUvForTexture);
```

The texture at (1.0,2.0):

[image]

Once I have the appropriate UV (newUvForTexture give me the image above).But what if I need to scale it down, something like this `newUvForTexture*2.0` while maintaining its offset? Can someone provide a GLSL code example of how to accomplish this?

**HERE IS A WORKING EXAMPLE:** https://codepen.io/miguel007/pen/VwGpjvm

Again this is what I would like to accomplish, is to scale it up or down while keeping the offset and no other textures appearing:

```c
      float scale   = 1.0/4.0;
      vec2 offset   = vec2(1.0,2.0);
      vec2 newUv    = (vUv+offset)*scale;
      gl_FragColor  = vec4(texture2D(u_tex,newUv).rgb,1.0);
      /* 
      vec2 scaledUp = newUv*.8;
      gl_FragColor  = vec4(texture2D(u_tex,scaledUp).rgb,1.0);
      or 
      vec2 scaledDown = newUv*2.0;
      gl_FragColor    = vec4(texture2D(u_tex,scaledDown).rgb,1.0);
      */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `clamp()` glsl function](https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=clamp) to stop the UVs from progressing beyond the desired min/max values:

```glsl
float scale = 1.0/0.25;
vec2 idx = vec2(1.0,2.0);
vec2 newUvForTexture = (vUv+idx) * scale;

// Get minimum & maximum limits of UVs
vec2 min = vec2(idx.x + 0.0, idx.y + 0.0) * scale;
vec2 max = vec2(idx.x + 1.0, idx.y + 1.0) * scale;

// Limit the range of UVs with clamp()
vec2 clampedUVs = clamp(newUvForTexture, min, max);

// Sample texture with clamped UVs.
vec4 tex = texture2D(texArray[0], clampedUVs);
```

You could probably optimize this further by performing the `* scale` multiplication only once, but this way it stays closest to your original code for clarity.

Here's a working demo using the above approach: https://codepen.io/marquizzo/pen/zYJwGMy

Comment: unfortunately, this solution doesn't work. maybe I'm confused about what part that should be scaled. 1) `newUvForTexture` gives me the UV I need at the desired index and scale. (second image).  2) clampedUVs Limit the range of UVs so multiplying clampedUVs by some value should allow me to scale down that specified texture to what I need `texture2D(texArray[0], clampedUVs*0.8);`.  but the texture is now offset and shows other parts of the atlas instead of scaling down.

Comment: If you could show me a working demo [like on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/aL15qox9/), I could probably help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: see edit for working example

Comment: @Memory1 It seems you didn't even try to implement my solution. Here's a working demo using the solution I suggested. Notice the `uniform u_zoom` to zoom in/out: https://codepen.io/marquizzo/pen/zYJwGMy

Comment: beautiful, it working perfectly fyi I tried the solution I just wanted to add the example code from my starting point. thank you.